# Hide "already up-do-date" message on git pull

Tags: git

I have a shell script which does (between a lot of other things) a simple git pull. The message of that command I write onto a log:

```
git pull origin release >>/home/git.log
```

Now I want to log only when "something happens". When nothing is to do I do NOT want to log the "already up-to-date" message.

Is there a switch or configuration on the git pull command to ignore the already up-to-date message but display everything else?

(I do not have any root access on that machine, so no command requiring sudo would work for me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

git has `--quiet` flag that suppress messages, but it will not work here since you want some of the messages. (And also it seems not to work on several of git versions).

I would suggest using a simple `grep` as part of the script.

```
git pull origin release | grep -v "already up-to-date"
```

The `-v` option inverts the match, meaning that it won't return results that match "already up-to-date".